# Can I drop my own templates into the OTB ExportWebMap Tool?

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, arcgis-10.1

At ArcGIS for Server 10.1, there is a print task installed by default.

Looking at the web-help, it states:

> The PrintingTools service included with ArcGIS for Server references a
>   preconfigured folder with 8 map layouts.  These include basic
>   designs in the 8.5 by 11 inches, 11 by 17 inches, A3, and A4 paper
>   sizes in both portrait and landscape orientations. **If you want to use
>   your own layouts, you can publish your own service** for printing web
>   maps

Despite this advice, I want to confirm if it is possible to include additional templates to this Out The Box service, as opposed to having to publish a separate service.

Looking at the Service in REST, I can see these templates.
I also found the corresponding templates under:
 `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\Templates\ExportWebMapTemplates`

If I drop a new 10.1 MXD into that folder, and restart the PrintingTools service (which now automatically clears the REST cache at 10.1), it will not pick up this new template.

[image]

**Is there any way to configure the underlying GP service behind Export Web Map to accept new MXDs?**

I did notice that if I edit one of these existing templates (e.g. add a North arrow) then these changes flow through.

Comment: Pro layout templates now used and located here
C:\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\ArcGIS\Resources\ArcToolBox\Templates\ExportWebMapTemplates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the nudge in the right direction from PolyGeo, I hunted down the model behind the service to this location:

*C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\ArcToolbox\Services\Printing Tools.tbx*

However, from my findings, I cannot see a way to edit this model to include additional layouts.  I cannot see anything in the properties of either the Layout Templates parameter or the toolbox properties to let me control this pre-defined list of MXDs.

[image]

I did spot an expression in the .tbx when inspecting it in a Text Editor, but manipulating this screws up the toolbox, and I do not want to be messing with text editors.

```
<param name="Layout_Template" displayname="Layout Template" type="Optional" direction="Input" datatype="String" expression="{MAP_ONLY | A3 Landscape | A3 Portrait | A4 Landscape | A4 Portrait | Letter ANSI A Landscape | Letter ANSI A Portrait | Tabloid ANSI B Landscape | Tabloid ANSI B Portrait}"><dialogReference>
```

So my answer is that, based on my findings,  it is not possible (let alone advisable) to add your own layouts to the OTB tool, but you need to [publish a new service to consume your own new layouts.](http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000057v000000)

Will be leaving this Q open for awhile, as would like someone to proove me wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the tool from which the OOTB Geoprocessing Service is created limits the MXDs it makes available to be opened via a choice list. If you can find that Python script tool then you should be able to add one more template MXD name to the choice list on that parameter.

Comment: How do you know its python behind the service, and not just a basic model using the new Export Web Map? But either way, any idea where this .py/.tbx is?

Comment: I'd assumed Python was in place to get at arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF but your Answer seems to indicate that ArcObjects has been used direct to wrap export functionality behind a tool that bypasses Python. I'll try to check 10.1 tonight to see if I can get at the parameters of that model. I *think* I should be able to but its always nice to be able to test. I did not look at this particular tool during 10.1 Beta so my answer was based on my 10.0 work doing similar things with GP services and arcpy.mapping.

Comment: I was also under assumption it used arcpy.  One huge plus point for us is that this tool carries across the graphics symbology (albeit maybe not transparency?) to the prints.  We could not do that with Arcpy.

Comment: Just checked the toolbox you found under the ArcGIS Server install and it looks like it has been locked.  It's probably always wise to configure away from the install folder anyway (especially if you have to support it) so I'd say writing an arcpy near-equivalent would be the only way open for me to use my own template MXDs in a print service for now.  I'm actually doing that for someone on Monday at 10.0.