# How do I retain transparency in graphics with exporting on the web?

Tags: arcgis-server, printing, arcgis-10.1

At 10 and 10.1 you can make use of arcpy.mapping to publish a gp service to do printing with.

[This is a sample](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8f16fdeef39c46b3952002b2d85ea5de) that does this:
[image]

As you can see, transparency is respected with the arcpy approach.

We have an application where the end-user can choose nearly any style they want for graphics.

- All Simple/Text/MarkerSymbols
- Any transparency or colour
- Any fill or line style
- etc

We hit limitations with trying to carry across these graphics across into an ArcPy service.

So we have been testing out the new 10.1 [Export Web Map tool](http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004w5000000) from the PrintingTool toolbox.

With some investigation on [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22466/can-i-drop-my-own-templates-into-the-otb-exportwebmap-tool), we determined that it was not a python script behind this tool, but appears to be using ArcObjects.

From initial tests, it has the benefit over ArcPy in that whatever is in my graphics layer in our web client, gets thrown across and drawn ok in the output PDF (using the draw toolbar and default OOTB print service with Flex 3.0 API).  However, transparency gets stripped out:
[image]

I was looking at the [ExportWebMap](http://resourcesbeta.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004w8000000) input parameter for the Export Web Map Tool, and trying to find out if there was something I could do to try and retain that transparency.

It does mention being able to set opacity on a layer, but I am unsure on how to manipulate one of the existing Flex samples to achieve this.

**Can someone provide a solution (any API) to retaining transparency using the new ExportWebMap tool at 10.1?**  Or is it a limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bjorn Svensson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2478/bjorn-svensson) has been in touch to let me know that this is a current bug within the pre-release Flex 3.0 API.  **It has been fixed at their end and will be in the final 3.0 API**

The ExportWebMap tool is a C++/ArcObject tool that you can use to create your own Print Service simply and quickly. While the same functionality is exposed via ArcPy called ConvertWebMapToMapDocument().

Under the hood, both makes call to the same C++ code and return results differently. As a result, both supports the same functionalities. Though ExportWebMap returns the print output in pdf/png etc. format, the arcpy function returns the mxd itself and at that point you have the full control to modify the mxd in any way you want.

2. **Transparency**: Yes, client side graphic’s transparency (both outline and fill) is maintained in the Print Output. Because of a bug in Flex API, the Print Task didn’t send transparency information correctly. Please try with one of the latest Flext API (I assume that’d be 3.0 Prelease).
3. **Symbology**: we support all simple fill/marker/text/line symbols as well as Picture marker/fill symbol for a WebMap FeatureLayer or client-side graphics. We don’t support cartographic line symbol or character marker symbol though or multi-layer symbol. In most of cases, the picture marker symbols should meet your requirement.

Comment: Can confirm its fine in final API.